# running git clone against AWS CodeCommits gets me a 403 error

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

My local laptop is a Mac.

1. The ssh key is configured properly. This is the content of ~/.ssh/config

```
Host barthea
Hostname git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
User AVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVQ
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/aws-aws.pem
```

Running ssh barthea gets me

```
You have successfully authenticated over SSH. You can use Git to interact with AWS CodeCommit. Interactive shells are not supported.Connection to git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com closed by remote host.
```

2. I created an IAM user bruce666 complete with password and access keys, made this user part of the "team" group.Then I created a policy that includes "AWSCodeCommitPowerUsers" and assigned this policy to "team".  And finally assigned bruce666 to "team". At this point, bruce666 can access any repo in CodeCommit through the management console.
3. I ran **aws config --profile bruce666**, fed in his access and secret key, his region and specified the format at json. At this point, I was able to create the rekha repo in CodeCommmit by running **aws codecommit get-repository --repository-name rekha --profile bruce666**
4. I can create a couple of dummy files, run **git init**, **git add .** , **git commit -m "1"**, **git add origin https://git-gitcode.amzonaws.com/repos/v1/rekha** , **git push -u origin master** And that operation will be successful.
5. However, when I run **git clone ssh://git-gitcode.amazonaws.com/repos/v1/rekha** , I get "fatal: unable to access 'https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/barthia/': The requested URL returned error: 403" What gives?

Answer (score 104):

On MAC, if above-mentioned tricks don't work, do the following:

1. Open Keychain Access
2. Search for CodeCommit. You should find this:

[image]

3. Select 'git-codecommit....' and press delete
4. Confirm the delete.

Now try again. It should work. You may have to do it again next time as well when you face the error 403.

One of the possible reason for this issue is the keychain password different than login password on your MAC.

Comment: This has stopped working for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: such a pesky feature of Keychain Access

Comment: Worked for me. I was not able to push anymore on my repo. I had to resubmit my password again.

Comment: Nothing happens when I click delete - no prompt, and no deletion.

Comment: This worked for me, but I need to delete it again before EVERY remote action (push, fetch etc). Anyone know how to fix this permanently?

Comment: If nothing happens when you click delete, that's potentially because there is a bug in the search function. Find the entry without using the search function and then hit delete.
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253223496

Comment: Thank you so much. Who would have thought Keychain Access would cause such problems. It worked after deleting the codecommit entry.

Answer (score 62):

I also face same 403 error while using git push command in windows. I done all settings mentioned in AWS docs, but non resolved my issue. After i reviewed git credential set via Windows Credential as shown in screen. I found instead of git https credentials, it set access key / secret key (don't know how).

```
Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager
```

[image]

Click on edit link, update credential with proper git credential generated for AWS User, everything worked fine.

Comment: Vote this one, is the fix for windows 10

Comment: Vote for this one !

Comment: In my case it listed the URL as the user name - no idea how that happend. inserting user and password there directly fixed it.

Comment: I didn't update credential, but just deleted it. Then windows ask about login and password again, I canceled it and finally git started to use credential-helper and successfully clone the aws repo.

Comment: I needed to do the same as @IlyaSheroukhov, don't know why but this worked :\ really sad this bug

Comment: Thanks for this hint, worked as a magic on Windows 10.

Answer (score 17):

[This helpful text is found on the AWS documentation for codecommit and Windows integration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-https-windows.html#setting-up-https-windows-credential-helper)

> If your installation of Git for Windows included the Git Credential
>   Manager utility, you will see 403 errors or prompts to provide
>   credentials into the Credential Manager utility after the first few
>   connection attempts. The most reliable way to solve this problem is to
>   uninstall and then reinstall Git for Windows without the option for
>   the Git Credential Manager utility, as it is not compatible with AWS
>   CodeCommit.
>
> If you want to keep the Git Credential Manager utility,
>   you must perform additional configuration steps to also use AWS
>   CodeCommit, including manually modifying the .gitconfig file to
>   specify the use of the credential helper for AWS CodeCommit when
>   connecting to AWS CodeCommit.
>
> Remove any stored credentials from the
>   Credential Manager utility (you can find this utility in Control
>   Panel).
>
> Once you have removed any stored credentials, add the
>   following to your .gitconfig file, save it, and then try connecting
>   again from a new command prompt window:

```
[credential "https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"]
    helper = !aws codecommit credential-helper $@
    UseHttpPath = true
```

> Additionally, you might have to re-configure your git config settings by specifying --system instead of --global or
>   --local before all connections work as expected.

This last part applied to my situation, though when I ran git config --system it did not function as expected but appended aws configure before the aws codecommit command.

So I had to run this in git to find the location of the config file for the system.

```
git config --list --show-origin
```

I then added the suggested section from AWS to both my c:/users/username/.gitconfig and my c:/ProgramData/Git/config files.

After that git push started working- even though I get the bogus error in front of my response of

```
"git: 'credential-aws' is not a git command. See 'git --help'."
```

Comment: This is was the most useful answer(at least to me). The mistake i did was to install git with credential manager utility. To work around this, you uninstall git, then install it and un check the credential manger utility. After that it worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: On linux to change .gitconfig:  `sudo nano ~/.gitconfig`

Comment: No need for sudo @GabrielPetersson

Answer (score 8):

I solved it.

The 403 error message is a specifically Git error message. I added the two AWS-specified helper commands:

```
git config --global credential.helper '!aws --profile bruce666 codecommit credential-helper $@'
git config --global credentials.helper UseHttpPath=true
```

and that took care of the issue.

The *.git/config* file in your local directory (before you clone the Codecommit repo that you had just created should look like this:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = false
[credential]
    helper = !aws --profile bruce666 codecommit credential-helper $@
    UseHttpPath = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/barthea
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

As specified in the *.git/config* file, you are cloning using https not ssh. I must not have used the default version of git that came with OSX because I did not run into any Toolchain issue.

Comment: no need to add an aws profile (--profile bruce666) just ```!aws  codecommit credential-helper $@``` will do. +1

Answer (score 7):

After running below commands, I had to add the below mentioned policy to my IAM user to solve this problem. [refrence](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/getting-started.html)

```
git config --global credential.helper '!aws codecommit credential-helper $@'
git config --global credential.UseHttpPath true
```

Policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "codecommit:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

## Issue (On Ubuntu)

> $ git clone
> https://git-codecommit.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/xx
> Cloning into 'xx'...
> fatal: unable to access 'https://git-codecommit.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/xx/':
> The requested URL returned error: 403

## Solution:

## Step 1:

```
git config --global credential.helper '!aws codecommit credential-helper $@'
git config --global credential.UseHttpPath true
```

**Check:**

```
cat ~/.gitconfig 
[user]
    email = your-email
    name = your-name
[credential]
    helper = !aws codecommit credential-helper $@
    UseHttpPath = true
```

## Step 2:

1. Services > IAM
2. Click on Users (Left panel)
3. Click on *your username* (main panel)
4. Click on `Add permissions`
5. Click on `Attach existing policies directly`
6. On `Filter policies`, type `AWSCodeCommitFullAccess`
7. Check the checkbox besides the policy, and click `Next: Review`
8. Click on `Add permissions`

## Result

> $ git clone
> https://git-codecommit.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/xx
> Cloning into 'xx'... 
> remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
> Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), 223 bytes | 223.00 KiB/s, done.

## Reference

1. [Getting started with Git and AWS CodeCommit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/getting-started.html)

Comment: Perfect solution, fixed it for me on Ubuntu running in Windows WSL2.

Answer (score 3):

For me the root cause of getting the error was that no matter which version of git I was using on OSX, GIT was always picking up the credential.helper config of using osxkeychain from the file:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/git-core/gitconfig
```

Getting rid of this solved the problem for me and has not broken anything.

Comment: Thank you! In my case, the first clone and commit worked for some reason - but then no go.

Answer (score 3):

My case in OSX.

The first step:

```
git config --global credential.helper '!aws codecommit credential-helper $@'
git config --global credentials.helper UseHttpPath=true
```

However, verifying `git config --list --show-origin`

```
file:/usr/local/etc/gitconfig   credential.https://git-codecommit.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com.helper=!aws codecommit credential-helper $@
file:/usr/local/etc/gitconfig   credential.helper=osxkeychain
file:/Users/mine/.gitconfig  user.name=my-user
file:/Users/mine/.gitconfig  user.email=my@gmail.com
file:/Users/mine/.gitconfig  filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
file:/Users/mine/.gitconfig  filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
file:/Users/mine/.gitconfig  filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
file:/Users/mine/.gitconfig  filter.lfs.required=true
file:/Users/mine/.gitconfig  credential.helper=!aws codecommit credential-helper $@
file:/Users/mine/.gitconfig  credential.usehttppath=true
```

**The first line was not present** before, and git was using `osxkeychain` with precedence. Hence, I had to do `git config --system ...`

```
cat /usr/local/etc/gitconfig                                             
[credential "https://git-codecommit.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"]
    helper = !aws codecommit credential-helper $@
    UseHttpPath = true
[credential]
    helper = osxkeychain
```

So the URL was specified in order to fallback in case another credentials are stored.

**Update**
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-ch.html

For some reason, **UseHttpPath = true** seems not to be added sometimes. So it can (should) be added under [credential]

Answer (score 3):

The following solution worked for a handful of devs that use Git Bash on Windows 10.

If you select Windows as your operating system on the "**Connect to your repository**" tab, the commands are formatted like this:

```
git config --global credential.helper "!aws codecommit credential-helper $@"
git config --global credential.UseHttpPath true
```

However, if you use Git Bash, select the "Linux, MacOS, or Unix" option instead. 
Note the single quote instead of double quote on the first line.

```
git config --global credential.helper '!aws codecommit credential-helper $@'
git config --global credential.UseHttpPath true
```

Best of luck.

Referred:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=198356
Posted by: mwhardesty

Answer (score 2):

fatal: unable to access 'https://git-codecommit.yourregion.amazonaws.com/v1/yourrepositoryname/': The requested URL returned error: 403

It occurs due to below regions

1. Make sure your user has `codecommitfullaccess` policy attached.
2. make sure your default region in local aws cli configuration and region in which repository created are same. If not reset the default region in aws cli command as below

> aws configure

3. make sure if repository present there.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this steps in aws [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-https-unixes.html)
Try this command after the steps

```
git config --system --unset credential.helper
```

Answer (score 0):

Something was wrong with my default aws credentials, I ran `aws configure` again with no profile, restarted terminal and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure that your AWS credentials not only have permission to access CodeCommit, but also that there are no blanket deny policies attached. In our organization we require MFA on all console accounts and this does cause programmatic access to have issues.

A good solution (if this is your issue) would be to create another IAM user without console access with the codecommit policy attached directly (in our case the MFA blanket deny is from the IAM group the user is a part of).

Clarification: This answer is for when you are using IAM credentials and the CodeCommit Git extension (rather than IAM Git credentials), although I suspect it is true in that case as well.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever it asks to enter Username and Password while trying to clone or pull the code from AWS, instead of copying the password manually enter it by typing each letter. This resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a permission issue.

You need to need to attach the **AWSCodeCommitFullAccess policy** to your IAM user to give you access to CodeCommit.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me the only option that worked was using git clone with the HTTPS (GRC) option
which gives a URL that starts with:

```
git clone codecommit::
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows 10, make sure you copy this:

```
[credential]
    helper = !aws codecommit credential-helper $@
    UseHttpPath = true
```

to these two configuration locations:

1. drive:\Users\UserName\.gitconfig
2. drive:\Program Files\Git\etc\gitconfig

Answer (score 0):

System Environment variables (I'm not sure how) were used to pre-specify the Region, access, and secret key. Changing these variables fixes the problem. The region, access, and secret key were all correct in `.aws/config` and `.aws/credentails`, but I needed to change the environment variables to make this work.