# git multiple credential helper

Tags: git, aws-codecommit

I have multiple remotes in my local git clone. Both of the remotes are using https to connect to git and need different credentials. I am using codecommit and hence the codecommit credential-helper for credentials. Is there a way I can use separate credential helper for different roots.

Comment: I quickly figured this out thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/13203623/743552

Comment: I added two lines with "helper=" in my ~/.gitconfig, as the article mentioned was possible.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to put the following in my ~/.gitconfig and my AWS CodeCommit and GitLab remotes (in the same repo) were able to successfully fetch.

```
[credential]
    helper = !aws --profile myusername codecommit credential-helper $@
    helper = manager
    UseHttpPath = true
```

One issue I did have though was: `"fatal: unable to access 'https://git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/myrepo/': The requested URL returned error: 403.`

I discovered this was due to another "helper = manager" located in another gitconfig when I upgraded my Windows Git install. I ran "`git config --list --show-origin`" so that I could see which file this was from (`file:C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/etc/gitconfig credential.helper=manager`). After commenting the lines out with semicolon `;`, the error disappeared. Moving that line into my ~/.gitconfig resolved the issue.

**UPDATE:**

[AWS updated their website with better information on using multiple credential helpers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-https-windows.html#setting-up-https-windows-credential-helper). Here is what my ~/.gitconfig looks like now:

```
[credential "https://git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"]
    helper = !aws codecommit credential-helper --profile myusername $@
    UseHttpPath = true
    ; NOTE: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-https-windows.html#setting-up-https-windows-credential-helper
    ; Setup username/password: https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?#/users/matt?section=security_credentials
[credential]
    helper = manager
```

If you are on a Mac and start see this answer on [cleaning up git credentials in OS X Keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53246180/358224)

Comment: One thing to add for Mac: If you somehow have an old entry in "Keychain Access" (Mac key manager), remove it to get everything working properly.

Answer (score 0):

- Create one store file for each username.

```
touch ~/.username-credentials
```

- Locally configure each repository with its appropriate store file.

```
git config --local credential.helper 'store --file ~/.username-credentials'
```

---

More about

[Git - Credential Storage](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage)